# javascript calculator 5 + 5 = 55?

Tags: javascript, calculator

Hey I made a javascript calculator and want the to try 5 + 5 it give me 55 other then 10 ? How ever if I try 5 / 5 it give me 1 fine if i try 5 - 5 it gives me 0 fine and same with times i don't under stand the problem with my code also want to  try console.log it doesn't work so I use document.write

this is my code

```
var Plus = function()
{
    var N1 = prompt("Enter first number");
    var N2 = prompt("Enter second number");
    var sum = (N1 + N2);
    document.write(sum);
} 

var Minus = function()
{
    var N1 = prompt("Enter first number");
    var N2 = prompt("Enter second number");
    var sum = (N1 - N2);
    document.write(sum);
}

var Division = function()
{
    var N1 = prompt("Enter first number");
    var N2 = prompt("Enter second number");
    var sum = (N1 / N2);
    document.write(sum);
}

var Times = function()
{
    var N1 = prompt("Enter first number");
    var N2 = prompt("Enter second number");
    var sum = (N1 * N2);
    document.write(sum);
}

var Answer = prompt("Plus ?, Minus ?, Division ? or Times ?");

    if( Answer === "Plus")
    {
        Plus();
    }
    else
    {
        if( Answer === "Minus")
        {
            Minus();
        }
        else
        {
            if( Answer === "Division")
            {
                Division();
            }
            else
            {
                if( Answer === "Times")
                {
                    Times();
                }
                else
                {
                    document.write("How did you get here?");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: var sum = ( +N1 + +N2);

Comment: or var sum = (1.0*N1+1.0*N2)

Answer (score 5):

`N1` and `N2` are strings, not numbers. Adding two strings together concatenates them, which is what your "error" is.

You need to parse them into numbers:

```
var N1 = Number(prompt("Enter first number"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this works for other operators but not plus is because "a" + "b" = "ab".

That said, you're adding strings. So "5" + "5" = "55"

If you first convert them to integers, it should fix this.

```
var sum = (parseInt(N1,10) + parseInt(N2,10));
```

Comment: You should pass a radix argument to `parseInt`: `parseInt(N1, 10)`. Without that, numbers with leading zeroes may be interpreted as octals by some browsers.

Comment: @Blender: Good call... I'd never come across that before but just looked into it to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

**Prompt** gets you the string format of input , you need convert it into integer for integer add operation.